# Grails Facet Search Implementation

Tags: hibernate, grails, solr, faceted-search

I am researching on using  full text and facet search implementation in grails 2.4.3 based app.
As per grails plugin page only Searchable Plugin is updated in 2014. 
Does hibernate search and solr plugin are also compatible with grails latest version or not?

And can some one provide example for facet search implementation in grails.
That will be very helpful
Thanks

Comment: Not an answer but there is plugin for elasticsearch (plugin was updated 1 month ago): http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch.

Comment: FFS, the framework is called GrailSSSS, not grail!!